# How to make <li> bullet show at the top of its content instead of the bottom?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was just wondering if there's a quick and easy way to make an <li> bullet show at the top of its content instead of the bottom. This is just a simple <ul> with 4 <li>'s. See picture below for reference.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VVsW.png)

[HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPshb.png)

Comment: Can you share CSS and HTML code please?

Comment: Can you please upload your code to this?

Comment: @yasgo  I edited and uploaded a picture since I have razor code that will cause errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I just need to add the `d-block` bootstrap class to the label to override the default `display-inline-block` CSS of the label.